# mount: cannot mount block device

Tags: linux, redhat, nfs, mount

I have nfs share mounted to RedHat server.

```
server:/NFS/Test on /test/test/nfs type nfs (ro,n......
```

Now I want bind mount each folder inside this share to other place.

```
sudo mount --bind /test/test/nfs/dir1 /test/test/dir1/dir1
```

And receiving this error:

> mount: block device /test/test/nfs/dir1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
>   mount: cannot mount block device /test/test/nfs/dir1 read-only

I want to mount as read-only not rw. But, it is not mounting, all permissions are okay. Do you have any suggestions? Or are there any requirements for mount --bind?
Thanks

Comment: No explanation, but  I would simply directly `mount server:/NFS/Test/dir1 /test/test/dir1/dir1`  rather than using a bind mount

Comment: I have already mounted this share to local directory with the command you provided, Now I am going to mount subfolders to another directory for another purposes. with bind option

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do is possible, from the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html):

The bind mount call attaches only (part of) a single filesystem, not possible submounts.  The entire file hierarchy including submounts is attached a second place by using:

```
mount --rbind olddir newdir
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried this one as well and the result is the same. I am mounting already mounted nfs share to local directory with bind option.